# How to get assocation from user in phpunit functional test using Symfony 2?

Tags: symfony, authentication, testing, phpunit

I have tests currently where I'm using the http_basic authentication as explained in the cookbook of Symfony 2.

However, I now get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getClient() on a non-object
```

for this code:

```
protected function getClient()
{
    /** @var User $user */
    $user = $this->getUser();
    /** @var UserClient $userClient */
    $userClient = $user->getUserClients()->last();
    return $userClient->getClient();
}
```

As I'm new to testing, and since this is a functional test, what is the best practice to get pass this error?

Comment: Do you really sure that you need to call `last()` method?

Answer (score 0):

You try to call `getClient()` method, but `$userClient` isn't an object, so you need to check `$userClient` object first

```
protected function getClient()
{
    /** @var User $user */
    $user = $this->getUser();
    /** @var UserClient $userClient */
    $userClient = $user->getUserClients()->last();
    if ($userClient) {
        return $userClient->getClient();
    } 
    return NULL;
}
```